# Vba to create multiple workbooks from one spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning, 
I have a spreadsheet with 600 columns and 500 rows (number of rows and columns is not always the same). i need to copy the first three columns ( which will be pasted in a new workbook )with the next 6 columns. So copy columns abc and defghi in a new workbook. Then copy columns abc again and the next six columns jklmno in a new workbook and the story goes on until we reach a column with no data. 
Is that thing even possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Did that answer your question or were you simply fishing to find someone to write all of the code for you?

Comment: Thank you very much mate. I am trying to find a piece of code that does this routine but i can't find anything on the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not on Excel at the minute so I can't test, but you should be able to infer what to do from this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExportData()

Dim varColumn As Long
Dim varColumnEnd As Long
Dim varRowEnd As Long
Dim varRowStart As Long
Dim varSplice As Long
Dim varName As String
Dim varCount As Long
Dim varBook As Workbook
Dim varPath As String

varRowStart = 1
varRowEnd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
varColumnEnd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column
varCount = 1
varSplice = 6

For varColumn = 4 To varColumnEnd

    If varColumn < varColumnEnd Then

        Set varBook = Workbooks.Add

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & varRowStart & ":C" & varRow).Copy
        varBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & varRowStart & ":I" & varRow).Offset(0, (varCount - 1) * varSplice).Copy
        varBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        varBook.SaveAs "C:/" & varName & "_" & Format(varCount, "00") & ".xlsx"
        varBook.Close

        Set varBook = Nothing

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much mate works great

Comment: No worries mate, glad I could help